# Is there any Moodle API that still exists?

Tags: android, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I'm a student, and I want to build an app based on information presented on our University Moodle service.
I went to this link: [Moodle api](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_Mobile_Building_the_app_for_Android)
but there is a warning line there that says:

> Warning: This page is no longer in use. The information contained on the page should NOT be seen as relevant or reliable

does any one have a suggestion how can I build this app? I built some apps that retrieve information from web before but none using Moodle api.

Comment: After navigating around a bit, it looks like that page was put together with version 2.4 in mind; that version is deprecated, and the current version is 3.2.0.

Comment: where can i find the api for this version?

Comment: It looks like you can view the API documents just by clicking on main page in the breadcrumbs or Development in the top bar.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522924/is-it-possible-to-have-my-app-communicate-with-moodle/41567522#41567522

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Category:Web_Services
Moodle has a mobile app. and if your school moodle admins enabled it in moodle configuration - you can download it (Android/IOS) and use it.